# A method to format font/ paragraph concatenated text inside of Google Sheet Cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I'm concatenating text using goole sheets, but I want to automatically format the text. Is it possible to add to the formula (I tried HTML tags, unsuccessfully)?

Sheets has the ability to display formatted text into a cell that you enter manually through some WYSIWYG editor. But that doesn't seem to work on concatenated text in a line by line fashion, though it will work on the entire cell.

I'm looking for a formula that can be used to process the concatenated text or a suggestion for what the best alternative would be, whether that is a plugin, appscript etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via a custom menu this way:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Scripts')
  .addItem('Format header', 'format_header')
  .addToUi();
}

function format_header() {
  var cell   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getCurrentCell();
  var text   = cell.getValue();
  var header = text.split('\n')[0];
  var style  = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).setFontSize(14).build();
  var value  = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(text).setTextStyle(0, header.length, style).build();
  cell.setRichTextValue(value);
}
```

It adds the command 'Format header' in menu 'Scripts' that formats a first line of the text in current cell as bold and size 14.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. what I am trying to do is to figure out a solution that will work for any text that appears in that box, perhaps I need an app script that will output based on a delimiter or an html tag? unless there is a way to do this inside of a formula

Comment: With a script you can parse any html-like delimiters of course. In this snippet a break line ('\n') is a delimiter. But there can be pretty anything as well. As for a formula, I have no idea how it could be done. I'm not an expert in formulas, alas.